# Collapse a pageblock section when another pageblock section collapsed

Tags: apex, pageblocktable, pageblock, pageblocksection

can someone let me know how to manage this?

Collapse a pageblock section when another pageblock section collapsed?

Answer (score 2):

The collapsing is done via Salesforce's javascript **twistSection()** function, so I suppose if you've got jQuery you could probably add an additional click event to the section marker that would select the marker for the second section and call the twistSection method on it as well

Comment: You might want to give OP a pointer to the Javascript function -- specifically `twistSection`